# Auto attached records get detached after commit

Tags: java, jooq

I have want to fetch a list of Relation records, and I'll use `.fetchInto(RELATION);` and I want to iterate over the list and commit each iteration to the database. This doesn't seem to be working for me because I get `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed` while updating the record. I don't have this problem with regular jOOQ queries. And it doesn't seem any connections are closed.

When I use `contact.attach(jooq().configuration())` it seems to be working again. How can I prevent it from detaching?

I start and commit a transaction through `JPA.em().getTransaction().*`.

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [update `Relation` set `Relation`.`organizationName` = ? where `Relation`.`id` = ?]; Connection is closed
    at org.jooq_3.15.1.MYSQL.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2979)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:643)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:349)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.storeMergeOrUpdate0(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:331)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.storeUpdate0(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:228)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.lambda$storeUpdate$1(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:220)
    at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:143)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.storeUpdate(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:219)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.update(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:156)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.update(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:151)
    at worker.taskprocessors.BulkContactEditWorker.execute(BulkContactEditWorker.java:144)
```

Example:

```java
var contacts = jooq()
        .selectFrom(
            RELATION
                .join(BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_CONTACTS)
                .on(
                    BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_CONTACTS
                        .CONTACT_ID
                        .eq(RELATION.ID)
                        .and(BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_CONTACTS.BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_ID.eq(bulkContactEditId))
                    .and(BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_CONTACTS.PROCESSED.isFalse())))
        .limit(batchSize)
        .fetchInto(RELATION);

if (!JPA.em().getTransaction().isActive()) {
  JPA.em().getTransaction().begin();
}

for (RelationRecord contact : contacts) {
  contact.attach(jooq().configuration()); // I have to add this line to make it work.
  contact.setOrganizationName("OrganizationName");
  contact.update();
  JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();
  if (!JPA.em().getTransaction().isActive()) {
    JPA.em().getTransaction().begin();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show example code that helps reproduce the problem? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've added example code.

Answer (score 0):

#### What's the problem

You're fetching your jOOQ `RelationRecord` values outside of a JPA transactional context, so that fetching runs in its own transaction (this is independent of jOOQ). jOOQ will always try to [`acquire()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html#acquire()) and [`release()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html#release(java.sql.Connection)) a connection for every query, and when that happens outside of a transactional context, then the connection will be effectively closed (e.g. returned to the connection pool). You should switch the order of starting a transaction and running the jOOQ query:

```java
// start transaction
// run jOOQ query
// iterate jOOQ results
//   run updates
// commit transaction
```

If you're using declarative transactions (e.g. Spring's `@Transactional` annotation), then you're less likely to run into this problem as your initial jOOQ query will more likely also be in the same transaction already.

#### Why did attaching work

When you explicitly attach the `RelationRecord` to the configuration, then you will attach a record that has been attached to the previously closed connection to the new configuration with the transactional connection. I'm assuming that your `jooq()` method produces a new `DSLContext` instance, which wraps the currently active `DataSource` or `Connection`.

#### Switch to bulk updates

However, if your example is all there is to your actual logic (i.e. you haven't simplified it for this Stack Overflow question), then why not just run a bulk update? It will be simpler and much faster.

```java
jooq()
    .update(RELATION)
    .set(RELATION.ORGANIZATION_NAME, "OrganizationName")
    .where(RELATION.ID.in(
        select(BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID)
        .from(BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_CONTACTS)
        .where(BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_CONTACTS.BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_ID.eq(bulkContactEditId))
        .and(BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_CONTACTS.PROCESSED.isFalse())
    ))

    // Since you're using MySQL, you have native UPDATE .. LIMIT support
    .limit(batchSize)
    .execute();
```

I'm assuming your actual example is a bit more complex, because you need to set the `PROCESSED` flag to true somewhere, too, but it's always good to keep this option in mind.

Comment: Even if I start the transaction at the start, and checking if it's active, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Disheart: I would need to see your complete setup, of `jooq()` and `JPA.em()`, and possibly other context. It's much more likely a configuration problem than a jOOQ problem...

Comment: The `ctx.connection.isClosed()` always returns false. There probably is a difference in how we use the DSLContext from jooq() and how record.update works, as the former does work.

Comment: Could it be that because `jooq()` uses `DSL.using(ourConnection)` and this connection is not used while fetching into relation records?

Comment: @Disheart: I really need to be able to see a *complete* setup to be able to understand what you're doing. This Stack Overflow page helps explain the challenge of understanding why something doesn't work, when I'm not sitting at *your* computer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. I'm sorry, I can't help you further before I can see *everything*. I have a lot of open support requests, and this one would take up a lot of my time if I have to re-iterate things comment by comment...